# JSTL: How to check if username is in the database

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to show user's details from database in "my profile" modal. I'm using JSTL in login.jsp page. This is what I tried (and some other variations) without any result. Database connection is OK!. Table name is `users` and I want to find the right user in the table. I get the `username` as request from `index.jsp` when a valid user log-in.

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users.rows}" >
<c:if test="${username}" == "${user.username}"> // <-- This is NOT working!
```

If `username` and `${user.username}` matchs then I want to show user's info in the modal like:

```
<c:out value="${user.fullName}"/>
<c:out value="${user.occupation}"/>
<c:out value="${user.email}"/>
<fmt:formatDate type="both" dateStyle="short" timeStyle="short" value="${user.joined}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was `<c:if test="${username eq user.username}">` It works fine now. I hope it will help someone else as well :)